# How to remove sands on cloth in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need remove these sands on cloth. but need keep the cloth's texture.

[image]

---

thx for all your answers, I finally did it use frequency separation method.

[image]

Comment: Isn't most of the texture the sand? So you want to keep the sand's texture just get rid of its color?

Comment: I want keep the cloth's texture, but remove the sand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fair bit of sand. How's this?

[image]

How I did it (I'm positive there are better ways out there but this seemed quick and it worked):

1) Took the lasso tool, circled the sand, and copied the selection onto a new layer above.

2) Gave new sand layer a mask and used a soft brush to feather/fade out some of the edges.

3) Gave sand layer a color overlay (layer>layer style>color overlay) of dark blue (the shirt color), set the blend mode to 'Hue', and lower the layer opacity to 35%.

4) Now back to the shirt layer (might be helpful to hide the sand layer for this) and Patch Tool the main sandy area to a lower right portion of the shirt. Try this a couple times until the area is smooth and not as sandy.

5) On the shirt layer still, Spot Healing brush any remaining sand bits around the main area.

With sand layer and shirt layer both visible you should be 90% of the way there

I also added some Color Balance (brought some of the cyan and blue back) and a Brightness & Contrast (raise the brightness and bring back some of the sand as shirt texture) on the sand layer (clipping mask some adjustment layers) but it's not too big of deal if you don't.

Like I said, I know there are better ways out there but I figured the something quick would work for this one, hope this helps!